# Text editor help needed

Tags: javascript, jquery

I came across this editor: http://jsfiddle.net/RRBHw/22/

My question is where do those values (bold, italic, unordered list) come from? All I see is

```
         <p>\
                <a href='#' class='bold'>Bold</a>\
                <a href='#' class='italic'>Italic</a>\
                <a href='#' class='unorderedlist'>List</a>\
            </p></div></div>");

                $('.bold', tb).click(function () {
                    formatText('bold');
                    return false;
                });
                $('.italic', tb).click(function () {
                    formatText('italic');
                    return false;
                });
                $('.unorderedlist', tb).click(function () {
                    formatText('insertunorderedlist');
                    return false;
                });
```

It doesn't seem right, yet it works. But then again how would I add more options to it (Such as h1, underline)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should take a look at the "`formatText`" function in that same code:

```
 function formatText(command, option) {
    iframe.contentWindow.focus();
    try {
      iframe.contentWindow.document.execCommand(command, false, option);
    } catch (e) {
       console.log(e);
    }
    iframe.contentWindow.focus();
 }
```

In particular, this line:

```
iframe.contentWindow.document.execCommand(command, false, option);
```

So if you use '`bold`' as a command for example, the HTML will be modified and be displayed in bold.

Here you have some documentation:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document/execCommand

And a possible list of commands if you want to extend it using the same way:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document/execCommand#Commands

Comment: Last question how would I pass a font-size to fontSize? Do I use something like `<font size="7"></font>`?

Comment: You need to pass a value with the font size when calling the "execCommand" method. Like for example: iframe.contentWindow.document.execCommand('fontSize', false, 3);